# Extend Store class to always execute a function after load on ExtJS

Tags: extjs, store

I am working on a project where we were asked to "patch" (they don't want a lot of time spent on development as they soon will replace the system) a system implemented under ExtJS 4.1.0.

That system is used under a very slow and non-stable network connection. So sometimes the stores don't get the expected data.

First two things that come to my mind as patches are:
1. Every time a store is loaded for the first time, wait 5 seconds and try again. Most times, a page refresh fix the problem of stores not loading.

2. Somehow, check detect that no data was received after loading a store and, try to get it again.

This patches should be executed only once to avoid infinite loops or unnecessary recursivity, given that it's ok that some times, it's ok that stores don't get any data back.

I don't like this kind of solutions but it was requested by the client.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?140693-Global-exception-handling-for-data-requests) should help with your question.

One of the posters suggests adding the below in an overrides.js file which is loaded in between the ExtJs source code and your applications code.

```
Ext.util.Observable.observe(Ext.data.Connection);
Ext.data.Connection.on('requestexception', function(dataconn, response, options){
     if (response.responseText != null) {
        window.document.body.innerHTML = response.responseText;
    }
});
```

Using this example, on any error instead of echoing the error in the example you could log the error details for debugging later and try to load again. I would suggest adding some additional logic into this so that it will only retry a certain number of times otherwise it could run indefinitely while the browser window is open and more than likely crash the browser and put additional load on your server.

Obviously the root cause of the issue is not the code itself, rather your slow connection. I'd try to address this issue rather than any other.